# Copy files from Azure BLOB storage to SharePoint Document Library

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, sharepoint-online, azure-powershell, azcopy

I cannot find a way to copy files\folders from Blob storage to a SharePoint document library.  So far, I've tried AZCopy and PowerShell:

*AZCopy cannot connect to SP as the destination

*PowerShell works for local files but the script cannot connect to Blob storage ( Blob storage cannot be mapped as a networkdrive)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else who needs to do this, AZCopy worked.  I just had to use a different destination.  When you map a SharePoint document library as a mapped drive, it assigns a drive letter but it also shows the UNC path.  That's what you have to use:

/Dest:"\\*Tenant*.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\Sites\*sitename*\*library*"

Comment: More Info: AZCopy10 uses different syntax and is much better.   
   azcopy10_0_8.exe copy "https : //STORAGEACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net/CONTAINER/FOLDER?sv=201[SAS TOKEN REDACTED]" "\\Tenant.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\sites\SITENAME\LIBRARY" --recursive --overwrite=false --log-level ERROR

Comment: Hey Doug - this doesnt seem to be correct syntax for sharepoint online. any help? thanks

Comment: I tried to use `az copy` to copy from local to sharepoint site "Shared Documents". 
It seems the command is not able to recognize the sharepoint url. and fails with error