# Copy documents to Azure Storage Container from sharepoint Library

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-blob-storage

I want Copy few sharepoint documents to Azure Storage Container using powershell script.

I am new to azure.Need help on this.

Comment: can you add what you have tried and error if you are facing any?

Comment: There's a simular question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54698611/copy-files-from-azure-blob-storage-to-sharepoint-document-library?rq=2 perhaps it can assist you

Comment: Kindly share share the script, what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

> Copy Documents to Azure Storage Container from SharePoint Library

You can use the script below to copy files from SharePoint to Azure Blob Storage using PowerShell.

**Script:**

```
$SiteURL = "https://<tenantname>.sharepoint.com/sites/<sitename>"
$FileServerRelativeURL = "/sites/<sitename>/Shared%20Documents/<files>"
$DestinationFolder ="C:\demo"
Try {
     #Check if the Destination Folder exists. If not, create the folder for targetfile
     If(!(Test-Path -Path $DestinationFolder))
     {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $DestinationFolder | Out-Null
        Write-host -f Yellow "Created a New Folder '$DestinationFolder'"
     }
    #Connect to PnP Online
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Interactive
    #Check if File exists
    $File = Get-PnPFile -Url $FileServerRelativeURL -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    If($File -ne $Null)
    {
        #Download file from sharepoint online
        Get-PnPFile -Url $FileServerRelativeURL -Path $DestinationFolder -Filename $File.Name -AsFile -Force
        Write-host "File Downloaded Successfully!" -f Green
    }
    Else
    {
        Write-host "Could not Find File at "$FileServerRelativeURL -f Red
    }
}
Catch {
    write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}

$account_name="venkat789"
$account_key="xxxx"
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $account_name -StorageAccountKey $account_key
 
$containerName = "test"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $DestinationFolder -File -Recurse
$files | Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Container $containerName -Context $context
 
# Delete the local file
Remove-Item $DestinationFolder -Recurse -Force
```

The code above downloads a file from a SharePoint site to a local temporary folder, then uploads it to an Azure Blob Storage container and deletes the temp folder in the local directory.

**Output:**

```
File Downloaded Successfully!

AccountName: venkat789, ContainerName: test

Name BlobType Length ContentType LastModified AccessTier SnapshotTime IsDeleted VersionId  
---- -------- ------ ----------- ------------ ---------- ------------ --------- ---------  
mountainview.png BlockBlob 51548 application/octet-stream 2024-03-19 07:07:19Z Hot False
```

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]